# Writing a dataframe with thousands of columns to HDFS takes a lot of time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, parquet

I am trying to execute an SQL query on Spark that generates a table with around 10,000 columns and want to write this to a parquet file on HDFS:

```
trial = spark.sql(sqlQuery)
trial.write.mode('overwrite').option("delimiter", "\100").parquet("path/to/HDFS/trial.parquet)
```

It seems that it takes a lot of time to write the table to HDFS. Is there anything I can do in order to improve the efficiency?

Comment: How many partitions is your dataframe; `trial.rdd.getNumPartitions()`?  Increasing this will increasing the number of parallel write processes.

Comment: @eduffy How can I increase the number of partitions for `trial` and at what stage should I repartition it?